# Using raw_input() without assigning a variable

Tags: python, variables, python-2.7, variable-assignment, raw-input

I've only recently begun learning python2, and this is the way I see `raw_input()`.

If suppose I write `name = raw_input("What's your name? ")` then I ask the user to enter something which gets stored as a string assigned to the variable `name`. By assigning it to `name`,  I can use it for whatever purpose I needed it later.

But what does using `raw_input()` without assigning the input to a variable accomplish? Also pressing enter at this point is supposed to continue with the script (so I have deduced, am I right?),  but where is this behaviour documented? In what kind of a situation would I use `raw_input()` without assigning to a variable? I couldn't find my answers in the official python documentation. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging purposes you may just want your code to pause for a second so you can analyse some `print` statements describing what's happening in your code. There's really not set reason for having this, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` can be used with `int()` to set the length of a loop based on what the user chooses without declaring a variable.